# error in creating executable for python script

Tags: python, py2exe, pyinstaller, cx-freeze, pybel

I have created a application using python2.7 also used pyqt for gui. I have also used pybel module for computations.

my application python file works properly. but when I try to create executable from that python file it gives me error.

[image]

I have tried using py2eye, cx_freeze and pyinstaller too.

I am wondering if the python file runs well after typing "python ui_MolecularTest.py" on command prompt, why I am unable to create executable from the same?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like pybel is having trouble preparing a list of supported formats.

Comment: ya i guess too. do u know how can i solve this issue and create executable out of it?

Comment: Nope, I've never worked with pybel. Try tweaking the code near that line, see what it's doing and what the problem is. A pybel mailing list might be able to help.